# T-SQL Select full rows with same column value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to show all rows that has a serial that exist in another row.

If I do like this it works

```
SELECT 
      [Serial]
FROM [x].[dbo].[Devices]
GROUP BY Serial
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

But when I add more select columns

```
SELECT [ID]
      ,[UUID]
      ,[Serial]
FROM [x].[dbo].[Devices]
GROUP BY Serial
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

I get

> 'ID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Why can't I select more columns?

How am I suppose to show the full rows?

Comment: Can you please explain with some sample data and show expected result

Comment: your error is because you are grouping by only `Serial` but Selecting 3 coloumns from which 2 are not specified in the grouping or have an aggregate-function.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a window function:

```
select *
from (
   select *, 
          count(*) over (partition by [Serial]) as serial_count
   from [x].[dbo].[Devices]
)  t
where serial_count > 1;
```

This is typically faster then joining to a sub-select with an aggregate.

Answer (score 2):

Hope you need this query, it will show all the rows that has a serial that exist in another row.

```
SELECT  D1.[ID]
        ,D1.[UUID]
        ,D1.[Serial]
FROM [x].[dbo].[Devices] D1
JOIN (  SELECT [Serial]
        FROM [x].[dbo].[Devices]
        GROUP BY Serial
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ) D2 ON D1.[Serial] = D2.[Serial]
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as ID and UUID are unique to the serial, try grouping by all columns.

```
SELECT [ID]
  ,[UUID]
  ,[Serial]
FROM [x].[dbo].[Devices]
GROUP BY Serial
  ,[ID]
  ,[UUID]
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: That gives 0 rows, while only selecting serial and grouping by serial gives 940

Comment: In that case, I can only assume that for every serial, you have many IDs and UUIDs.

Comment: ID is unique, but UUID is not. but can't i simply group many values but only filter on serial having the same value in other rows?

Comment: @Arulkumar beat me to it above.  Go with that :)